# Show a menuflyout from a button on another flyout Win 8.1 XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, callisto

I've got a scenario in my app where I show a popup from a appbar button in Windows 8.x (using XAML/C#).
Prior to Win 8.1, I used Callisto to show the popup. In Win 8.1, I'm trying to use the built-in Flyout and MenuFlyout controls.

Simple flyouts and menu flyouts work - but when I try to show a menu flyout off of a button that is itself in a popup/flyout - it dismisses the previous flyout/parent flyout - which is not the desired behaviour.

Here is some code to reproduce the issue:

https://github.com/krishna-nadiminti/FlyoutTest

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Ideally - I don't want to go back to using Callisto in the Win8.1 project - because I want to use the same code as part of my framework to show flyouts and secondary flyouts in universal apps.

[image: A simple menu flyout from an app bar works]
[image: Flyout that contains a button which will bring up a menu]
[image: On clicking ... the secondary menu flyout hides the previous/parent flyout!]